# Why "new" dataset table is deleted when trying to update existing dataset table in Esri Insights workbook?

Tags: table, insights-for-arcgis

I have an established Insights workbook, with designated cards.

The data being used comes from "Table A" when I add "Table B" (updated data) and attempt to 'Update' Table A - which should be a very simple process according to all of Esri's documentation - Table B is deleted from the table of content and Table remains the same.

Both tables are formatted identically and contain the exact same fields.

Why is a "new" dataset table deleted when trying to update an existing dataset table in an Esri Insights workbook?

Comment: I suspect that there are very few Insights for ArcGIS users amongst our community.  Consequently, I think it will help to attract potential answerers if you can provide detailed steps for how someone new to Insights for ArcGIS may be able to get to where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out myself. To update an existing dataset table it, and the "new" dataset table, must have populated coordinate (X/Y) fields. When the original dataset table is added to your Insights workbook click on the 'enable location' and select your geographic coordinate system (GCS). When adding the "new" dataset table, that will replace the existing one, **DO NOT** enable location on the incoming table, after you have added it to the workbook's table of contents. Switch to 'Analysis view' in the workbook click 'update' on the dataset bubble you are updating and follow the prompts. You're done!